# Which menu/status icons' guidelines should I follow for an app that will support Android 2.2 and later?

Tags: android, menu, icons, status

In the guidelines found in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html for menu and status icons, we have distinctive design approach for Android 2.2 and earlier and Android 2.3 and later.
My app is going to support Android 2.2 and later. I was thinking that i should follow the 2.3 and later guidelines. 
Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow multiple styles by creating subfolders with the correct android version specifiers inside your res/ folder (e.g. drawable-v11 for API 11 - [check the official documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)). So I suggest supporting multiple styles.

This is obviously a bit more work. To make this easy for standard icons like notifications, check out [the Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html). This is a small webapp that creates these icons to your specifications and builds a zip with the multiple styles, already sorted into the different res/ subfolders.

Comment: Thx alex! Love the Android Asset Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On thing you could do is include assets for both builds, and at run time, figure out if you're on 2.2 or 2.3, and show the appropriate assets.  This can be done with [build.version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155165/determine-api-level-for-platforms-1-6) method for earlier releases.

Of course, if you want multiple icons, I don't believe this method would work, as that needs to be build into the android manifest.