# Error on AVD with API Level 4

Tags: android, android-emulator

My app is working fine on 2.2 and 2.3 emulators. But when I tried to load the app on emulator with API level 4 (1.6), it showed the force close dialog. The logcat log is:

```
12-27 18:30:34.279: E/dalvikvm(1501): Could not find method com.twintechs.itsr.SplashScreenActivity.overridePendingTransition, referenced from method com.twintechs.itsr.SplashScreenActivity$1.run
12-27 18:30:34.279: W/dalvikvm(1501): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1280: Lcom/twintechs/itsr/SplashScreenActivity;.overridePendingTransition (II)V
12-27 18:30:34.279: W/dalvikvm(1501): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x006c
12-27 18:30:34.279: W/dalvikvm(1501): VFY:  rejected Lcom/twintechs/itsr/SplashScreenActivity$1;.run ()V
12-27 18:30:34.279: W/dalvikvm(1501): Verifier rejected class Lcom/twintechs/itsr/SplashScreenActivity$1;
12-27 18:30:34.289: D/AndroidRuntime(1501): Shutting down VM
12-27 18:30:34.289: W/dalvikvm(1501): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
12-27 18:30:34.289: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): java.lang.VerifyError: com.twintechs.itsr.SplashScreenActivity$1
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.twintechs.itsr.SplashScreenActivity.<init>(SplashScreenActivity.java:152)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
12-27 18:30:34.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 18:30:34.310: I/dalvikvm(1501): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-27 18:30:34.310: E/dalvikvm(1501): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not good idea. Because in any reason on old SDK version we get cast exception.
I think we need use reflection. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3155838/238089)